# Replace chart code of data-ui-options attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, echarts

I'm new with this and I'd like to know how can I replace the chart code into attribute data-ui-options unsing JQUERY.

```
<div id="graficoHell" data-ui-jp="echarts" data-ui-options="{
          xAxis: {
              data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
              axisTick: {show: false},
              axisLabel: {
                  formatter: 'barGap: \'-100%\''
              }
          },
          yAxis: {
              splitLine: {show: false}
          },
          animationDurationUpdate: 1200,
          series: [{
              type: 'bar',
              itemStyle: {
                  normal: {
                      color: '#ddd'
                  }
              },
              silent: true,
              barWidth: 40,
              barGap: '-100%', // Make series be overlap
              data: [60, 60, 60, 60]
          }, {
              type: 'bar',
              barWidth: 40,
              z: 10,
              data: [4, 60, 13, 25]
          }]
      } " style="height:300px" >
```

I tried the same code as string into JavaScript but it did not work.

```
$('#graficoHell').attr('data-ui-options', "same_string_into_data-ui-options");
```

All examples I saw, was using echarts object, but the template I bought is in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is an old question I may answer it anyway.
You can use the element.dataset function in order to query / change data of an html element.

Querying the data according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
<div id="user" data-id="1234567890" data-user="johndoe" data-date-of-birth>John Doe</div>


const el = document.querySelector('#user');

// el.id == 'user' 
// el.dataset.id === '1234567890'  
// el.dataset.user === 'johndoe'
// el.dataset.dateOfBirth === ''
```

Updating data:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#user');
el.dataset.dateOfBirth = '1960-10-03';
```